# wordpress: insert category in post via mysql query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, categories

i want to add a category in a wordpress post using mysql query. I have 5k entries and I don't want to manually edit them.

Does anyone here know how can I insert a category in a post using mysql query insert?

Comment: You also can add category with this function `wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $terms, $taxonomy)`..
May be it help you...

Comment: how about adding category for specific post?

Comment: I used wp_set_post_terms().  Is there's a way to make the process fast?  I need to update 30k entries... i tried this function for 1000k entries but it is taking long...